# Create an id array from mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, laravel

How do I create an id array from a mysql query that only selects the ID.
So I want to get the array(id, id, id);

Here is my code:

```
$group = User::find($user)->group()->get(array('group.jid'));
```

The current return of the code:

```
[

   {
    "jid": 1
   },
   {
    "jid": 3
   }

]
```

What do I do so I can get `jid: 1,3`? So I can add it to a `where in` query?

```
WhereIn('id', $group)->get();
```

Comment: do you want those numbers in one array or in one string ?

Comment: Try this `User::find($user)->group()->lists('jid');` It should return an array with `jid`

Comment: @Altrim this is promising but I get `Column 'jid' in field list is ambiguous`. So I changed it to `groups.jid`. But still the same error.

Comment: @user3134069 I don't know how you've setup the relations but if you have everything setup correctly and if you read the docs on `selects` http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects you'll see the `lists` method returns exactly what you want.

Comment: @Altrim I got it. Just added a select before the list. If you would make that an answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a list of column values you can use the method `lists` on the query

`User::find($user)->group()->lists('jid');`

I guess you get the error about the id being ambiguous because you have the same column name on the parent query so you have to explicitly select that.